# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when trying to write to file

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to save the image file got by requests.get()

```
def get_image_file(class_path,image_id):
    r = requests.get(BASE_REQUEST_URL+'/image/'+image_id+'/download',  stream=True)
    print(r.url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(IMAGE_PATH+class_path+str(INCR)+'.jpg', 'wb+') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            print("Image saved")
    else:
        print('Can not save the image.')
```

So, if image is benign, image will go to 'benign' folder.
When I call the function

```
get_image_file('benign/','5436e3acbae478396759f0d5')
```

Here what I get:

```
https://isic-archive.com/api/v1/image/5436e3acbae478396759f0d5/download
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "image_fetch.py", line 59, in <module>
   get_image_file('benign/','5436e3acbae478396759f0d5')
File "image_fetch.py", line 34, in get_image_file
     with open(IMAGE_PATH+class_path+str(INCR)+'.jpg', 'wb+') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:   '~/tf_files/benign/0.jpg'
```

I thought the problem is in the write permission.I tried to use 'wb','wb+','a+', but nothing helped.

Comment: What are the values of `IMAGE_PATH`, `class_path` and `INCR`

Comment: The file name seems to start with a quote `'` (as you can see there is no closing one). Is it an error when copying the message error or is the quote part of the filename?

Comment: IMAGE_PATH = '~/tf_files/', class_path = 'benign/', INCR=0 is the increment which increments each time image downloaded to numerate the images.

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki No, quote is just a copy/pasting mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/tf_files` isn't a valid path, unless you're working in a shell; the `~` gets expanded to your home directory by `bash` and co., not by the OS.  If you want to have tildes in paths in Python, you should run them through [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) before doing the `open`:

```
path = IMAGE_PATH+class_path+str(INCR)+'.jpg'
path = os.path.expanduser(path)
with open(path, 'wb+') as f:
    # ...
    pass
```